# Forms : each state for each field vs consolidation in one state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form for customizing the result of the chart. This form has 8 fields, some of the fields share the same logic of validation but with different message errors.

I created a separate state for each field which is a separate event handler ( change event ).  Though my code looks structured and easy to understand, I find there is DRY code logic.

```
const Page = () => {
  const [debtShare, setDebtShare] = useState("");
  const [creditTerm, setCreditTerm] = useState("");
  const [interest, setInterest] = useState("");
  const [assurance, setAssurance] = useState("");
  const [maintenance, setMaintenance] = useState("");
  const [currentElectricityPrice, setCurrentElectricityPrice] = useState("");
  const [feedInTarif, setFeedInTarif] = useState("");
  const [infaltionRate, setInflationRate] = useState("");
  const [installationDate, setInstallationDate] = useState("");

  const onDebtShareChange = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    isValidChartField(
      event,
      isInteger,
      inRange,
      setDebtShare,
      "Der Anteil des Fremdkapitals sollte zwischen 0 und 100 liegen",
      0,
      100
    );
  };

  const onCreditTermChange = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    isValidChartField(
      event,
      isInteger,
      inRange,
      setCreditTerm,
      "Die Kreditlaufzeit sollte zwischen 0 und 100 liegen",
      0,
      100
    );
  };

  const onInterestChange = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    isValidChartField(
      event,
      isInteger,
      inRange,
      setInterest,
      "Der Zinssatz sollte zwischen 0 und 100 liegen",
      0,
      100
    );
  };

  const onAssuranceChange = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    isValidChartField(
      event,
      isInteger,
      inRange,
      setAssurance,
      "Der Versicherungswert sollte zwischen 0 und 100 liegen",
      0,
      100
    );
  };

  const onMaintenanceChange = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    isValidChartField(
      event,
      isInteger,
      inRange,
      setMaintenance,
      "Instandhaltung sollte zwischen 0 und 100 liegen",
      0,
      100
    );
  };

  const onCurrentElectricityPriceChange = (
    event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    isValidChartField(
      event,
      isFloat,
      inRange,
      setCurrentElectricityPrice,
      "Der aktuelle Strompreis sollte zwischen 0 und 1 liegen",
      0,
      1
    );
    // Addional check to remove the 0 when the user clicks backspace button
    // You can remove this check to understand the issue
    // This is related to the float numbers
    if (!event.currentTarget.value) {
      setCurrentElectricityPrice("");
      return;
    }
  };

  const onFeedTarifChange = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    isValidChartField(
      event,
      isFloat,
      inRange,
      setFeedInTarif,
      "Der Einspeisetarif sollte zwischen 0 und 1 liegen",
      0,
      1
    );
    // Addional check to remove the 0 when the user clicks backspace button
    // You can remove this check to understand the issue
    // This is related to the float numbers
    if (!event.currentTarget.value) {
      setCurrentElectricityPrice("");
      return;
    }
  };

  const onInflationRateChange = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    isValidChartField(
      event,
      isInteger,
      inRange,
      setInflationRate,
      "Die Inflationsrate liegt zwischen 0 und 100",
      0,
      100
    );
  };

  const onInstallationDateChange = (
    event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const { value } = event.currentTarget;

    // Remove all non-numeric characters from the input
    const numericValue = value.replace(/\D/g, "");

    // Format the date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format
    const formattedDate = formatDate(numericValue);

    setInstallationDate(formattedDate);
  };

// more code

}
```

I want to refactor the code and create consolidate state called `params`, but I found some difficulties with validations:

```
const Page = () => {
  const [params, setParams] = useState({
    debtShare: "",
    creditTerm: "",
    interest: "",
    assurance: "",
    maintenance: "",
    currentElectricityPrice: "",
    feedInTarif: "",
    inflationRate: "",
    installationDate: "",
  });

  const onParamChange = (
    field: string,
    event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const { value } = event.currentTarget;
    setParams((prevParams) => ({ ...prevParams, [field]: value }));
  };

 let isValidValue = true;
    switch (field) {
      case "debtShare":
        isValidValue = validateDebtShare(value);
        break;
      case "creditTerm":
        isValidValue = validateCreditTerm(value);
        break;
      case "interest":
        isValidValue = validateInterest(value);
        break;
      // Add other cases for other parameters...

      default:
        break;
    }

    if (isValidValue) {
      setParams((prevParams) => ({ ...prevParams, [field]: value }));
    } else {
      // Handle invalid input, e.g., show an error message
    }
```

I want to understand **when and where** to choose between each pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping single state is easier to maintain when you have similar fields, e.g., test inputs or checkboxes.

In case you have some complex validations (And you are validating on input or change event), different for different form fields, you might want to keep states separate.